# Can someone tell me how to obtain the thumbnail from a Blogger post using PHP/Zend?

Tags: php, blogger

Can someone tell me how to obtain the thumbnail from a Blogger post using PHP/Zend?

Comment: I can tell you that thumbnail is not spelled with an e.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the thumbnail is an image which sits in a Blogger post? You'll need to retrieve the HTML document (look for "retrieving an URL in PHP"), pick out the URL of the thumbnail (find the pattern in the HTML and look up "regular expressions" to create an automatic extractor) and download the image from the retrieved URL.

Or maybe there's an RSS feed which contains the URL you're looking for?

Or do you mean you want an image of the page?

As you can tell by the slightly negative comment above, you might want to try to elaborate a bit on your problem, but I hope this might give you a start into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to at least make an attempt, post what you have, ask for pointers, and not ask for others to do your work for you.

Comment: True, but this should have been a comment.